# NullPointerException when I call popBackStack(TAG, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) and fragments with shared elements

Tags: android

I use sharedElements for animate transition between screens and when I try clear backStack (2 fragments) I got this NullPointer.

This is my code:

```
supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(TAG,POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

And this stack-trace:

```
? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.Collection.contains(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.util.MapCollections.retainAllHelper(MapCollections.java:479)
    at android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap.retainAll(ArrayMap.java:161)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.captureOutSharedElements(FragmentTransition.java:799)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.configureSharedElementsOrdered(FragmentTransition.java:698)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsOrdered(FragmentTransition.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:134)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2379)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:853)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set `sharedElementsReturnTransition = null` in my `Fragment` and it fix `Exception`. But if you press back button your shared elements doesn't work - so I replace `Fragment` to separate `Activity` for resolve problem with backstack.